# Get value of multiple text fields store it to var and send it to CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

i have multi input type=text and i want to get all values of it to these fields and store it to var to send it via post to codeigniter controller

example code:
html

```
<input type=text value='value1' name='in1'>
<input type=text value='value2' name='in2'>
<input type=text value='value3' name='in3'>
```

js

```
$('#check').click(function() { 
    var postData = $('[type=text]').value();///THIS IS LINE I NEED TO FIGURE OUT
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?=base_url()?>patients/check',
        data: postData,
        success: function(html{$('#results').show();$('#results').html(html);}})});
```

so i want codeigniter controller patients function check to be able to see posted data with names=$in1 $in2 etc..

Comment: To be more specific use 
`var postData = $('input[type=text]').value();`
and then use either :
[http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)
or 
[http://api.jquery.com/serialize/](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use .serialize() if the only inputs in that form are the ones listed above. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
var postData = $('form').serialize();
```

This will package the data as a string:

```
'in1=value1&in2=value2&in3=value3'
```